# Categorizing Images with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement a few sections on my personal site to show/hide certain images.  Ex: Print / Web / UI / ALL. Once one if these are clicked, it will hide everything BUT that link.  Does anyone know of a somewhat simple way to do this using jQuery?  Here is my code is set up now:

```
<div class="boxgrid slideright">
<img class="cover" src="images/xxx.jpg"/>
<h3>Some title</h3>
<p>some text<br/><a href="images/xxx.jpg" rel="group" 
     class="fancybox">View &raquo;</a>  </p>    
</div>
```

I've looked online and SO and have had no luck.  Sorry if I missed something somewhere and thanks in advance!

Comment: What? You want to click a link to filter the images you're showing (clicking 'print', will show 'print' images, but hide the others), or you want to click a link to hide *all* images *except* the one you linked to?

Comment: Yes, I want to add links to corresponding images.  So, if say, Web is clicked, it will only show images related to web and hide all the others.  But also looking to add an ALL button that will reset everything.  I'm by no means a jQuery master, but figured it could be achieved somehow.  Thanks!

Comment: In which case I think my answer might suit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation that works well enough to give you an idea for development:

```
$('#controls li a').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = this,
            $that = $(that),
            id = that.id,
            gallery = $('#gallery');
        if (id == 'all') {
            gallery.find('img:hidden').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        else {
            gallery.find('img.' + id + ':hidden').fadeIn(1000);
            gallery.find('img').not('.' + id).fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });​
```

This is based on the following HTML structure:

```
<ol id="controls">
    <li><a href="#" id="web">Web</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="canvas">Canvas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="print">Print</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="all">All</a></li>
</ol>
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/dexter.png" class="web" />
    <img src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/mandark.png" class="canvas" />
    <img src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/drPooh2.png" class="print" />
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ebrnj/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).
- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Comment: You're very welcome; I'm glad to have helped! (And, really, thank you for the accept!) =)

Comment: The only thing I have to figure out is the way I have it set up now, I'm using the "FancyBox" jQuery gallery.  So when you hover oven an image, it slides out to reveal a caption underneath it.  So the <img> already use a class.

Comment: Classes aren't mutually exclusive, so that isn't necessarily a problem. However it might be worth asking a second question about how to combine the two approaches if it's presenting difficulties? If you do, then please consider posting a demo that reproduces your problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or similar. That way we can see your (representative) code in action, and play with it to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you actually want to do, but according to your question, here is an answer:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    $('a').each(function(){
        if($(this) !== $self) $(this).hide();
    });
    $('img').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give them all the same class, but unique id's. Then, attach an onclick to all elements with that class, and use `$.each()` to hide all of them who pass:

```
if(item.attr('id') != this.attr('id'))
```

Per your comment, you could do "show all" like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick = "ShowAll()">Show all</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowAll(){
        $(".commonClassName").each(function(index, item){
            item.show(); 
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery to access the `id`, just use `item.id != this.id`

Comment: How would I implement a "Show All" linK?

Answer (score 0):

just hide everything then show the one that was clicked, pretty simple...

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('a').hide();
    $(this).show();
});
```

Comment: I want everything to be visible at first.  Then have an option to filter out certain groups, but I see where your going.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'title' attribute of the img tag to store the category of that image.

```
<div class="boxgrid slideright">
    <img src="images/xyz.jpg" title="print" alt="" />
    <img src="images/abc.jpg" title="web" alt="" />
    <img src="images/def.jpg" title="print" alt="" />
    <img src="images/jkl.jpg" title="ui" alt="" />
    <img src="images/123.jpg" title="web" alt="" />
</div>
```

Then, give your 'a' elements a corresponding class.

```
<a href="#" class="web">Web</a>
<a href="#" class="print">Print</a>
<a href="#" class="ui">UI</a>
<a href="#" class="all">All</a>
```

Then in js:

```
$('div.boxgrid.slideright a').click(function(ev) {
    if($(this).hasClass('all')) {
        $('div.boxgrid.slideright img').show();        
    }
    else {
        $('div.boxgrid.slideright img[title="' + $(this).attr("class") + '"]').show();
        $('div.boxgrid.slideright img:not([title="' + $(this).attr("class") + '"])').hide();            
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the title of your question, you are seeking for categorization and the name of the CSS selector class is derived from classification and categorization, so, you should classify every category of your images under the same class name. i.e give the attribute class for each image you want to categorize it class='print' class='web' and so on.

In jquery you should do something like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.print').click(function(){

$('.print').css('display','none');

$(this).css('display','inline');

}) ;
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' value="b1" class="print" />
<input type='button' value="b2" class="print" />
<input type='button' value="b3" class="print" />
<input type='button' value="b4" class="print" />

<input type='button' value="bA" class="web" /><input type='button' value="bB" class="web" /><input type='button' value="bC" class="web" />
</body>
</html>
```